# Where best to discuss requirements for a new application?

Tags: discussion

In case [my question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/49354/requirements-tracking-tool-free-alternative-to-ibm-rational-doors) asking for a gratis alternative to IBM's Doors requirements tool doesn't get an answer here, I am thinking of developing one myself.

Ironically, I would have to have requirements for that :-)

I could work them out myself/just try to clone Doors, but I think I would get better results by collaboration.

Where ought I to ask/might I get the best help?

- Meta or chat?
- This site?
- [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/)?
- [Software enginnering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)?
- A non-S.E site?

Comment: I think SR Meta & main would not fit – you know our site is about recommending software that meets given requirements, not the other way around. No idea what other SE site it would fit on, but suggest another bullet point: A forum (I don't know which) would fit best, as requirements depend a lot of the environments, which again are quite subjective – so this would rather be a discussion.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of a forum, but forgot to add it. Actually, I can probably just ask around the office. Also, I found some free command line only solutions to which I might add a GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is a good question, then it means all of your requirements are in it, so you don't need any further discussion and can start implementing right away in your favorite programming language.

But maybe you want to make the software useful to other people, and thus you need to see whether your requirements are also the requirements of other people, or whether there is a good compromise that can make the software attractive to both you and many other people. Such investigation is not on-topic on any SE site, but there are other places to ask, for instance in your office as you said, on a specialist casual forum where most people are probably interested in such software, or you could write a questionnaire and have people fill it using some form of targeted advertisement.

Comment: A question here on SR cannot contain all the requirements. That would be too specific and never get an answer. It can contain some high level concept requirements, maybe. A student here has written a 140 page document discussing the requirements for an internal application - not to mention a real world application for customers.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: a non-SE site and I don't know which.

> Where ought I to ask/might I get the best help?
>
> Meta or chat?

Not Meta, because that's for discussion about how the site works, not how some other programs shall work.

Also not chat, since the chat rooms need to be on the same topic as the site itself (at least that's what the description says, I doubt it's true for all chat rooms on Stack Overflow).

> This site?

No. The requirements needed for implementing a software are much more detailed that the requirements for suggesting existing solutions.

Thus, I slightly disagree with @Nicolas' answer. The part "all of your requirements are in it" is simply not true. That would be a 50+ page document which does not fit on this site.

> Open Source?
> Software enginnering?

I don't know any Stack Exchange site that has requirements as on topic. I'd like to see "requirements" in an Area51 project. Might still turn out to not fit for single requirements but rather requirements concepts.

> A non-S.E site?

Maybe. There are so many, one of them has to support this ;-)

One could perhaps create a Github project for the requirements only. The discussion could be done via the Github Issues. Once the requirement is clear, it could be added to the repository using a diffable file format and the Issue gets closed.

Thoughts: you have traceability of requirements via the Git history. You could implement linking by writing requirements in Markdown and use links.

Once the requirements are done, create a new repository for implementing the application.

Even cooler: if it works like a compiler. As early as possible, write the requirements for the software with that software. Just don't do it like Enterprise Architect, who seem to never have used a UML diagram to design their UML diagram tool ;-)

Comment: +1 for creating a GitHub project, that's indeed a great way to get started. People can star it, submit issues, send pull requests to enhance the README, document the domain using the wiki, and even fork.